# Why do I have to refresh the network interface to get shared ethernet working?

Tags: networking

I am sharing ethernet from my Mac running OSX 10.8 to the Rasp. Upon boot, there is no network connectivity and no IP address assigned, even though my Mac claims it's assigned a host IP of 192.168.2.1 and a client IP of 192.168.2.2.

If I run `ifconfig` on the Rasp via a USB keyboard I see no IP address assigned. If I then run `sudo ifdown eth0` / `sudo ifup eth0` I get the proper IP.

Here's the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

Also, when I first run `sudo ifdown eth0` I see the following if it is of any help:

```
Listening on LPF/eth0/[mac]
Sending on LPF/eth0/[mac]
Sending on Socket/fallback
sDHCPRELEASE on eth0 to 192.168.2.1 port 67
send_packet: Network is unreachable
send_packet: please consult README file regarding broadcast address
```

Is it probable that the problem is on the Mac's internet sharing and not on the Rasp? At my office where I'm testing this I don't have ethernet anywhere near the display to try out a normal network cable.

Answer (score 4):

Need either 'auto eth0' or 'allow-hotplug eth0' in your original interfaces file otherwise the network device won't be brought up automatically unless specfied manually.

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Should fix the problem. I prefer allow-hotplug vs auto since auto brings it up always (often causing long pauses while it tries to connect), whereas allow-hotplug only brings up eth0 when a cable is connected and 'good'. (much better chance of connecting when there's a cable inserted!)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the fault is your setup, you can follow a few short steps:

1. **Assign a Static IP to the Ethernet cable.**

   Go to `System Preferences -> Network`. Then assign the IP by changing the IP in the IP box.
2. **Internet Sharing**

   Go to `System Preferences -> Sharing -> Internet Sharing`

   Share connection from:

   To computers using: Ethernet
3. **Configure eth0 interface on Raspberry Pi**

   Go to terminal, and type in the following:

   ```
   sudo vim.tiny /etc/network/interfaces
   ```

   Assign a static IP, and set the gateway to the Mac Ethernet interface's IP address (what you set before.) To do this, type in the code below:

   ```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
   auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.2.2
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   gateway <STATIC IP ON MAC>
   ```
4. **Test your internet connection**

   Open Midori and attempt to connect to the net.

Credits: http://blog.afkham.org/2013/02/how-to-connect-raspberry-pi-to-internet.html

Hope that that was helpful!